# is a named pipe right for this situation?

Tags: c#, c++

There are 3 projects:  `MyEXE` and `MyDLL` in C#, and `TheirEXE` in C++.

All three projects are on the same computer, which I can upgrade if required.  I use `TheirEXE` every day.  I plan to get `TheirEXE` to use `MyDLL` for added functionality. I was told I would need to write a C++ wrapper for `MyDLL` because `TheirEXE` is `COM`.  The details are frankly over my head but they will help so I assume it will work.

If I can get `TheirEXE` to reference `MyDll`, then I want a fast `named pipe` or some form of fast data transfer between `MyDLL` and `MyEXE`, capable of transferring in either direction a few dozen distinct 50 to 200 byte packages per second with high reliability.

Security is not an issue.  Is this possible? Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The bandwidth requirements are extremely small, just keep in mind that if you have down-to-millisecond hard latency requirements Windows (or any other preemptive multitasking OS) isn't going to cut it (you are always subject to the scheduler's whims, and to its tens of milliseconds time slices).

Answer (score 1):

You can use named pipe or even a standard TCP-Socket (what way it would be ready to do it remote). I personally would go for the TCP-Socket but its a matter of personal taste I would say.